# can't get the values of selected row in Oracle Jet ojetable

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

i have an oracle jet table which is  like that

```
 <table data-bind="event: {ojbeforecurrentrow: currentRowListener},
      selectionMode: {row: 'single'},
      ojComponent: {component: 'ojTable', 
        data: dataSource,
        columns: [
            {headerText: 'Student Id', field: 'Id'},
            {headerText: 'FirstName', field: 'FirstName'},
            {headerText: 'LastName', field: 'LastName'},
            {headerText: 'BirthDate', field: 'BirthDate'},
            {headerText: 'Gender', field: 'Gender'}
        ]
    }">
</table>
```

and the js file looks like that

```
self.currentRowListener = function (event,ui) {
      var current = ui.currentRow;
          alert(current);
           };
```

the alert value is Undefined , so i can't get the value of selected row

to set it in input text

what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this:

```
self.currentRowListener = function (event) {
     {
            var data = event.detail;
            var newCurrentRow = data.currentRow;
            alert(newCurrentRow );
            var oldCurrentRow = data.previousCurrentRow;

    }
```

For reference for selectionListener
    [Oracle Jet Table Events](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=eventTable)